# Change Windows Key shortcuts on Windows 8

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

On Windows 8, I noticed that the keyboard shortcuts for doing stuff is quite centered around the windows key. An example would be win + type, to search/launch applications.

The problem is, that I do not have a Windows key on my keyboard. So is there any way to change these keyboard shortcuts? Preferably to ctrl + alt?

Comment: You can but it will break other functions using the Win key in Windows 8, some of which are nice.

Comment: Cr-48's don't have a win key so it may well be broken anyways :)

Comment: As a note, it seems that pressing Ctrl + Esc corresponds to pressing the Win key.

Comment: I wonder which keyboard in that era doesn't have the Windows/Super/Meta/Command... key?

Answer (score 5):

Download <strike>[SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2011/12/sharpkeys_35.html)</strike> (also can be found [here](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com)) and remap a less frequently used key to <kbd>Win</kbd>. On an older machine with an otherwise fantastic 101-key PS/2 keyboard (that's 15 years old and going strong!), I used the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for this purpose, but the choice is yours. Be careful however and don't remap any important keys!

Edit: [Similar apps](http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows), but personally I've been using SharpKeys for ages over multiple Windows versions, and it just works.

Comment: When I click the first (official) SharpKeys link you provided I get `ESET NOD32 Antivirus - Access denied - Access to the web page was blocked by ESET NOD32 Antivirus. The web page is on the list of websites with potentially dangerous content.`

Comment: @amiregelz: Weird, was fine earlier but now I am getting that message as well. Maybe the domain got hacked/hijacked or something, because otherwise I have been accessing it for years now and can't see the developer knowingly adding malware. Thanks for the heads up though, people should definitely use the second link for now.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to edit the [Scancode Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx) in the registry.
*Warning:* Extremely difficult.

The scancode for the Windows key is `E0 5B`.

You can use [this utility](http://www.benf.org/other/scanmapset/index.html) to generate the registry key.

Comment: +1 Nice, first time I saw that method, learn something new every day here on SU.

Answer (score 2):

Make your <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key trigger the <kbd>Windows Logo</kbd> key instead.

1. save as caps.reg:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
>   "Scancode
>   Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,5c,e0,3a,00,00,00,00,00

2. double click to import into registry
3. reboot

from: http://mattshaw.org/news/window-map-caps-lock-to-windows-key/