# Changing shortcut keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change windows key shortcuts on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/473370/change-windows-key-shortcuts-on-windows-8)

Is it possible to change shortcut keys in Windows 8? The reason I'm asking this is because I have a CR-48 running Windows 8 and it doesn't have a Windows key :P