# Change Windows 8 Print Screen button behavior

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change windows key shortcuts on Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/473370/change-windows-key-shortcuts-on-windows-8)
>   [Changing shortcut keys](https://superuser.com/questions/494558/changing-shortcut-keys)

In Windows 8, I can press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Printscreen</kbd> button to save the screenshot automatically

Is there a way to change this buttom combination? For example, is it possible to change this to just <kbd>Printscreen</kbd> alone? So that by simply pressing <kbd>Printscreen</kbd>, it automatically saves the screenshot for me?

Comment: Do you mean `Fn` key of the `Windows` key?

Comment: Look into SnagIT or Greenshot. Both better than the integrated software in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following combinations have worked before Windows 8 and still work in Windows 8:

- <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> works without pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> key. It puts the copy of the screen to the clipboard.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> copies the currently active window to the clipboard.

The new <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> simply does additional work of saving the image into a PNG file.

---

I doubt you could change it to something different without 3rd party tools. There are lots of screen shot tools which can provide options to change the key combination to make screen shot.

Comment: It can be changed without a 3rd party app, click the link under the question above made by Matthew Wong

Comment: which link is it?

Comment: @Chin The link to the duplicate question: [Change windows key shortcuts on Windows 8](http://superuser.com/q/473370/80304). Anyway it's either a registry hack which remaps keys, or a 3rd party tool.