# How do I reassign win x in windows 8 to open chrome?

Tags: windows, windows-8, shortcuts, hotkeys

and for that matter how do I reassign any win+ combo?
(I am using a small software called winhotkey but it can only assign free letters with the win button - and Windows 8 has almost all the letters already assigned - I would like to reassign them to do things that I need - how do I do that?

Comment: keyboard letter (alphabet - a,b,c,d...).

Comment: Have you tried [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/)?  Also you can refer to [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/99681-windows-81-and-win-key-shortcuts-oddity/)

Comment: m... from some reason avast seems to think that  AutoHotkey is suspicious and does not allow me to install it...

Comment: Is Chrome pinned to your taskbar? If so you already have a win+(1-9) combo for it.

Comment: Related to this. Has some otherways of doing it other then AHK. http://superuser.com/questions/473370/change-windows-key-shortcuts-on-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a key remapping program.

There are outside a lot of them which could help you to do what you want. E.g. [KeyTweak](http://windows.appstorm.net/how-to/hardware/how-to-remap-your-keyboard-with-keytweak/) but **the most rich feature set is available in** [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which enable to write scripts, simple or complex. (You need to write a script to remap a key). I suggest it for you, you need to give a look at the documentation of [hotkeys](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and the [run](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Run.htm) command

You have to write a script like this:

```
#k::
#K::
Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
return
```

### Step by step:

1. Make a new text file
2. Paste the the script in it from above
3. Save as myscript.ahk
4. Double click on the file
5. Good! You are done! Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>

This will remap both Win+k and Win+K to start Chrome. ( # is stand for Win key.)

**Note:** After the remapping you don't need to run the remapping program, it write the changes to the registry. So you can even delete the program after you set the remapping.

Comment: As I wrote AutoHotkeyy is suspicious (by avast) so I can't download it.
Besides AutoHotkeyy what other options are there? ( KeyTweak doesn't seem to work with key combinations).

Comment: U can ignore the Avast alert, because it is a false positive. U can check it out here: https://www.virustotal.com/hu/file/689a4e7c0b4192cd19710107f10c5b635a755e2bb019d2e3300e6b17bc0340ca/analysis/1432934240/

Comment: Wow it worked! thank you!

I actually changed the code (it said that you had a duplicate line).

Follow up questions:
1. If I want to have a few more shortcrust - should I put them in the same ahk document or create a new one for each shortcrust?
2. Where should I save these documents (does it matter or can I put them in any folder on the computer?).
3. I am guessing that even after I activate them I can't erase them? will they automatically work even after restart? or should I re-activate them after each restart?

Comment: Oh - I didn't notice this line:
"After the remapping you don't need to run the remapping program, it write the changes to the registry. So you can even delete the program after you set the remapping."
Great!

Comment: Actually I just tested this and apparently when I close down the program it doesn't work - so it does not seem to change the registry from what I see...

Comment: Hi! I just tested and not worked for me too, but it should, I will look into it and report back

Comment: Thanks - let me know - currently I have two different items in my notification area - I made two shortcrust - however if I will make 5 shortcrust - I will see 5 items - this isn't a good way of doing things... If there is a way to make this change permanent it will be much better.